# Batch - How to use .tmp files to name output same as input after muxing?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

How to use *.tmp files to name output file same as original after muxing?

All *.mkv, *.mp4 and *.avi files inside the current directory and it's subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have ever thought what you try to do here: read data from a file and write modified data to same file at same time? How should this work?

There are applications which support that by reading from file `test.mkv` and in case of output file being same as input file write the output to a temporary file like `~test.tmp`. Once entire input file is processed and all data are written to temporary output file completely, the application deletes the input file and renames the temporary output file to name of input file.

It looks like `mkvmerge` does not support that. So you need a batch file for this task.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == ""   goto Help
if "%~1" == "/?" goto Help

if not "%~2" == "" (
    if /I not "%~f1" == "%~f2" (
        rem Optional output file specified being different to input file.
        mkvmerge.exe "%~1" -o "%~2" --no-subtitles
        goto :EOF
    )
)

mkvmerge.exe "%~1" -o "%~dp1~%~n1.tmp" --no-subtitles
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
move /Y "%~dp1~%~n1.tmp" "%~1"
goto :EOF

:Help
echo %~nx0 inputfile [outputfile] 
echo/
echo   inputfile    name of input file (required)
echo   outputfile   name of output file (optional)
echo/
echo The input file is replaced on no output file being specified.
echo/
pause
```

The batch file must be executed with `test.mkv` without or with path as argument.

**Note 1:** I don't have installed `mkvmerge.exe`. So this batch code is not tested related the `mkvmerge` command lines. And I don't know if `mkvmerge` terminates with an exit code greater 0 on an error used here to determine if input file can be deleted and temporary output file can be renamed to input file using command **MOVE** which is like using **DEL** and **REN**.

**Note 2:** Additional code might be added like testing if input file really exists and is a file and not a folder, or code to delete temporary file on error and still existing after `mkvmerge` terminated, etc.

For processing all *.avi, *.mkv and *.mp4 files in current directory and producing *.mkv files with deletion of original file:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /ON *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 2^>nul') do (
    mkvmerge.exe "%%~I" -o "~%%~nI.tmp" --no-subtitles
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        del "%%~I"
        move /Y "~%%~nI.tmp" "%%~nI.mkv" >nul
    )
)
```

For processing all *.avi, *.mkv and *.mp4 files in current directory and all subdirectories and producing *.mkv files with deletion of original file:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /ON /S *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 2^>nul') do (
    mkvmerge.exe "%%~I" -o "%%~dpI~%%~nI.tmp" --no-subtitles
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        del "%%~I"
        move /Y "%%~dpI~%%~nI.tmp" "%%~dpnI.mkv" >nul
    )
)
```

Command **DIR** outputs on using parameter `/S` instead of just the names of matching files in current directory the file names with full path of any matching file in entire directory tree.

For that reason `%%~I` references in last batch code the file name with file extension **and with full path** instead of just file name and file extension because of different output of command **DIR**.

`"%%~dpI~%%~nI.tmp"` expands to `"Drive:\File path\~File name.tmp"` while `"~%%~nI.tmp"` expands just to `"~File name.tmp"`. And `"%%~dpnI.mkv"` expands to `"Drive:\File path\File name.mkv"` while `"%%~nI.mkv"` expands just to `"File name.mkv"`.

Those small modifications make the batch file above work for all files in entire directory tree.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` used in second batch code to suppress the error message output by command **DIR** to handle **STDERR** in case of no file found matching any of the wildcard patterns by redirecting the error message to device **NUL**. In this special case redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character by Windows command interpreter on parsing **FOR** command line, but later as redirection operator on running **DIR** command line by **FOR** in a separate background command process.

And read the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).